# How does the *getenv function actually works when passing "PATH" as parameter?

Tags: c, path, environment-variables

According to [tutorialsonpoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getenv.htm):

> The `*getenv` function searches for the environment string pointed to by
> **name** and returns the associated value to the string.

> Where **name** is the C string containing the name of the requested variable

That page provides a simple example after that description, but such example doesn't explain step by step how this function actually works. So I seeked the code of this function in the net, and I managed to get a "replica" of the `*getenv` function called `*_getenv`, here it is:

```
char *_getenv(const char *name)
{
    int i, j;
    int status;

for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    status = 1;
    for (j = 0; environ[i][j] != '='; j++)
    {
        if (name[j] != environ[i][j])
        {
            status = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (status)
    {
        return (&environ[i][j + 1]);
    }
}
return (NULL);
}

getEnv = _getenv("PATH");
```

I know that the variable `environ` points to an array of pointers to strings called the "environment".  The last pointer in this array has the value `NULL`. Meaning that, in the first for cycle this function will loop over the array until it finds a `NAME` called `NULL`

What I don't get is what happens in the second for cycle, where the final condition to be met is `environ[i][j] != '='` and also the **if statement** where `(&environ[i][j + 1])` is returned, I mean, **why is it adding 1 to the j counter when returning the address**?

Comment: The second loop is effectively performing a `memcmp`, and the `j + 1` index refers to the first character of the *value* of the environment variable, i.e. everything after the equals sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what happens in the second for cycle,

The function checks if the value before `=` is equal to `name`.

```
name       = "somevariable"
environ[i] = "somevariable=somevalue"
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ----------- are these parts equal?
```

So compare if each byte of `name` is equal to `environ[i]` up until `environ[i][??] = '='`, so:

```
bool are_equal = true; // assume they are equal
for (j = 0; environ[i][j] != '='; j++) { // for each character in environ[i] up until equal sign
    if (name[j] != environ[i][j]) { // check if bytes are equal
        are_equal = false; // if they are not, we notify and break
        break;
    }
}
if (are_equal) { do_smthg() }
```

> why is it adding 1 to the j counter when returning the address?

`environ[i][j]` points to `'='`.

```
environ[i] = "somevariable=somevalue"
                          ^ ------------ [j]
                           ^ ----------  [j + 1]
```

We want to return the pointer to the value, excluding the `=` sign, so the function returns a pointer to `envron[i][j+1]`.